# data-sly-list how to check for first item

Tags: list, aem, sightly

Using data-sly-list I can iterate over a list object in Sightly, but how can I check for first

```
<li>
```

and add a specific class to it ?
Also, how to display every item separately ? for now my list looks like one LI with all items separated by coma. (`<li> item1,item2,item3 </li>`)

```
<ol data-sly-list="${currentPage.title}">
     <li>${properties.title}</li>
</ol>
```

I did try with:

```
<div data-sly-test="${!first}">
```

but didn't worked... any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list), you can use the `itemList` variable for this:

```
<ol data-sly-list="${['a', 'b', 'c']}">
  <li class="${itemList.first?'first':''}">${item}</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard AEM example templates and components, `jcr:title` is a single value field, so iterating `${currentPage.title}` will only generate one list item.
Your code should look something like this:

```
<ol data-sly-list="${currentPage.title}">
     <li class="${itemList.first?'first':''}">${item}</li>
</ol>
```

But I am not sure, what you are up to. Is `jcr:title` a multi value field in your page component? Or is it single value and contains a comma separated list?

If `jcr:title` is a multivalue field, then there's the next problem, as the method `getTitle()` from `com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page` returns a String value and not a list value.

You'd have to use the `properties` object then instead:

```
<ol data-sly-list="${properties.jcr:title}">
     <li class="${itemList.first?'first':''}">${item}</li>
</ol>
```

That should do the trick for you.

My advice would be to switch `jcr:title` back to a single value field if possible in order to keep the internal APIs working and add another field instead (i.e. `myTitle`) that could be a multi value field.

Comment: jcr:title it is a multi value field, I would like to display those as a list and add a specific class to first item if that make a sense ?